# Aptos Blockchain Node unable to sync properly after switching to fast sync. What to do?

Tags: synchronization, blockchain, nodes, aptos

We've been running a testnet node for 6 days but unfortunately the node hasn't been able to sync properly. We joined the validator set on the 10th and let the node sync till the 13th after which we switched to fast sync(https://aptos.dev/nodes/validator-node/operator/connect-to-aptos-network#using-docker) as mentioned in the docs but even with that method in the last 3 days, we have been unable to sync properly.

`testnet-vnode-validator-1  | {"level":"ERROR","source":{"package":"crash_handler","file":"crates/crash-handler/src/lib.rs:39"},"thread_name":"sync-driver-5","hostname":"c6149384e385","timestamp":"2022-12-14T23:59:49.040270Z","message":"details = '''panicked at 'Fast syncing is currently unsupported for nodes with existing state! You are currently 181852156 versions behind the latest snapshot version (386913673). Either select a different syncing mode, or delete your storage and restart your node.'`

Answer (score 1):

Your node is panicking after switching to fast sync because it still has partial synced state using the full sync method.

As mentioned here (https://aptos.dev/guides/state-sync#fast-syncing), to fast sync, you need to start with an empty DB (i.e., wipe the DB) and restart the fast sync process.

Given you're wanting to sync a completely new node with no state, I'd recommend using a direct DB snapshot provided by other entities, e.g., BwareLabs: https://bwarelabs.com/snapshots.

You should just be able to download their testnet db snapshot and overwrite your db with the files